# Running custom code after a new user registers (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to run some custom code after a new user registers (specifically I want to add an ubercart order for the new new customer). Where's the right place to add this code? I'm currently looking at hook_user_insert(), however from the documentation I'm not sure this is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to insert the php code manually .